# Base change under Galois cover

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite morphism between quasi-projective varieties, where $Y$ is smooth. Let $Z\to Y$ is a Galois cover. If the base change $Z\times_YX\to Z$ is a finite  étale cover, can we conclude that $f$ is also étale?

Comment: Yes. This is EGA IV, Proposition 17.7.4.

Comment: @abx Thanks for your answer. I think that it is requires that $Z\to Y$ is flat. But for a Galois cover, this is not necessarily true, am I right?

Comment: This may depend on what you call a Galois cover. Most references (e.g. the Stacks project) assume even that it is étale, which is more than you need. With $Y$ being smooth, it is hard to imagine a definition which would not imply flat.

Comment: @abx Do you mean that this is true: if X is a quasi-projective normal variety, and $G\subset Aut(X)$ is a finite group. Assume that $Y:=X/G$ is smooth, then $X\to Y$ is flat?

Comment: Yes, at least in characteristic 0, or if the order of $G$ is prime to the characteristic.

Comment: @abx Thanks. Do you have a reference or a proof for that please?

Comment: This is a bit indirect, but I don't know a more direct reference: Bourbaki *Algèbre commutative* ch. X, example b) p. 33 implies that $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, hence flat over $Y$ by miracle flatness.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of the kind of general statements one can deduce from EGA and SGA. Suppose that we have a morphism $f : X \to Y$ of schemes. Assume

1. $f$ is locally of finite type
2. $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible
3. $Y$ is normal
4. $f$ is dominant
5. there is a surjective morphism $g : Z \to Y$ of schemes such that the base change of $f$ by $g$ is unramified (eg etale).

Then $f$ is etale.

Namely, by [Tag 0475](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0475) we find that $f$ is unramified and then by the discussion in [Tag 0GS7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0GS7) we find that $f$ is etale (use normal $\Rightarrow$ geometrically unibranch). See also SGA 1, Exposee 1, Cor 9.11.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a more general statement than that in EGA IV.